# Efficient implementation of Fisher's Exact Test in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to implement [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) in Haskell, so given four natural numbers a, b, c, and d, I want to calculate the formula:

p=((a+b)! * (a+c)! * (b+d)! * (c+d)!) / (a! * b! * c! * d! * (a+b+c+d)!)

I have tried 3 implementations, but a need a more efficient one:

Solution 1:

```
module Main where

import Data.Ratio

factori n = fact_acc n 1

fact_acc 0 a = a
fact_acc n a = fact_acc (n-1) $! (n*a)

a = 1
b = 9
c = 7
d = 3

n1 = (factori (a+b)) `div` (factori a)
n2 = (factori (a+c)) `div` (factori c)
n3 = (factori (b+d)) `div` (factori b)
n4 = (factori (c+d)) `div` (factori d)
numer = n1 * n2 * n3 * n4
denom = factori (a+b+c+d)
p = (fromIntegral numer) / (fromIntegral denom)

main = do
    print denom 
    print p
```

Solution 2 (sorry for the long lines):

```
module Main where

factori n = fact_acc n 1
fact_acc 0 a = a
fact_acc n a = fact_acc (n-1) $! (n*a)

mul_from_to m n = mul_acc m n 1
mul_acc m n a = if (m==n) then (n*a) else mul_acc (m+1) n $! (m*a)

compute_p a b c d
     | ((a+b)>(a+c) && (a+b)>(b+d) && (a+b)>(c+d) && a<b && a<c && a<d) = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori a) * (mul_from_to (a+b+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+b)>(a+c) && (a+b)>(b+d) && (a+b)>(c+d) && b<c && b<d)        = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori b) * (mul_from_to (a+b+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+b)>(a+c) && (a+b)>(b+d) && (a+b)>(c+d) && c<d)               = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori c) * (mul_from_to (a+b+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+b)>(a+c) && (a+b)>(b+d) && (a+b)>(c+d))                      = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori d) * (mul_from_to (a+b+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+c)>(b+d) && (a+c)>(c+d) && a<b && a<c && a<d)                = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori a) * (mul_from_to (a+c+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+c)>(b+d) && (a+c)>(c+d) && b<c && b<d)                       = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori b) * (mul_from_to (a+c+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+c)>(b+d) && (a+c)>(c+d) && c<d)                              = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori c) * (mul_from_to (a+c+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((a+c)>(b+d) && (a+c)>(c+d))                                     = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori d) * (mul_from_to (a+c+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((b+d)>(c+d) && a<b && a<c && a<d)                               = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori a) * (mul_from_to (b+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((b+d)>(c+d) && b<c && b<d)                                      = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori b) * (mul_from_to (b+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((b+d)>(c+d) && c<d)                                             = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori c) * (mul_from_to (b+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | ((b+d)>(c+d))                                                    = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (c+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori d) * (mul_from_to (b+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | (a<b && a<c && a<d)                                              = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori a) * (mul_from_to (c+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | (b<c && b<d)                                                     = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori b) * (mul_from_to (c+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | (c<d)                                                            = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (b+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (a+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (d+1) (b+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori c) * (mul_from_to (c+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))
     | otherwise                                                        = fromRational (fromIntegral ((mul_from_to (a+1) (a+b)) * (mul_from_to (c+1) (a+c)) * (mul_from_to (b+1) (b+d))) / fromIntegral ((factori d) * (mul_from_to (c+d+1) (a+b+c+d))))

a = 50000
b = 910
c = 11
d = 300

p = compute_p a b c d

main = do
  print p
```

Solution 3:

```
module Main where

import Data.Ratio

factorial n = factorials !! pred n
factorials = scanl1 (\acc x -> acc * x) [1..maxim]

a = 1
b = 9
c = 7
d = 3

maxim=a+b+c+d

n1 = (factorial (a+b)) `div` (factorial a)
n2 = (factorial (a+c)) `div` (factorial c)
n3 = (factorial (b+d)) `div` (factorial b)
n4 = (factorial (c+d)) `div` (factorial d)

numer = n1 * n2 * n3 * n4
denom = factorial (a+b+c+d)

p = (fromIntegral numer) / (fromIntegral denom)

main = do
  print denom
  print p
```

Comment: There are probably many ways to make this code marginally more efficient, including by compiling it with different options, adding type signatures, etc. etc., as well as algorithms that are more efficient w/r/t computational complexity. There are also much more efficient solutions that sacrifice some accuracy. You should clarify the question w/r/t what you mean by "more efficient". Also your code doesn't seem to be formatted correctly.

Comment: I am looking for time efficiency.

Comment: I've tried to make it work with Int64 using a somewhat naive approach, it didn't work even for N=1000 because of overflows. Vaguely related: [An accurate computation of the hypergeometric distribution function](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=151274) + some scattered bits information [here](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/hypergeometric_dist.html), maybe use that as an inspiration. There, they compute everything "log primes" first, and then use divide-and-conquer to multiply subresults avoiding overflow...

Answer (score 6):

You compute

```
factorial (a+b) `div` factorial a
```

several times, with varying values of `a` and `b`. This can be improved by only multiplying the numbers between `a` and `a+b`; this reduces the total number of multiplications and avoids doing the division entirely, so should help some.

Depending on the scale, a tree-fold rather than a strict left-fold can improve the performance of doing lots of multiplications (because multiplying numbers of approximately the same magnitude is more efficient than multiplying one large and one small number). Something like this:

```
foldb' :: (a -> a -> a) -> a -> [a] -> a
foldb' f z = go where
    go [] = z
    go [v] = v
    go long = go (adjacent long)

    adjacent (x:y:rest) = let !h = f x y in h : adjacent rest
    adjacent short = short
```

You can then use `foldb' (*) 1` for computing products slightly more quickly than your explicit recursions.

I think these two improvements will be pretty marginal, though. They're certainly not asymptotic improvements. (Update: in my tests, using a tree-fold is actually a pretty big win: `factorial 100000` takes 943ms with `foldl'`, 18ms with `foldb'`, a 50x speedup.)

Comment: that is called **Pochhammer function** or **rising factorial** function.  Sort and pick the largest two elements to reduce (x1+x2)!/(x1+x2+x3+x4)! for the largest gain.