# Improving efficiency in Stirling numbers calculation

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I've been trying to explore the possibilities of recursion in Haskell, but I don't know much about improving efficiency when facing large recursions. Today, I wanted to make a function that calculates Stirling numbers of second kind:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = helper n 1
    where
        helper 1 a = a
        helper n a = helper (n-1) (a*n)


stirling :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
stirling n 1 = 1
stirling n 2 = ((2 ^n)- 2) `div` 2
stirling n k
    | k > n      = 0
    | k == n     = 1
    | k == (n-1) = (factorial n) `div` (factorial 2 * (factorial(n-2)))
    | otherwise  = stirling (n-1) (k-1) + k *(stirling (n-1) k)
```

I've been trying to create an auxiliary function, just as in the factorial definition, that could avoid the inconvenience of Haskell´s lazy evaluation taking too many memory resources. I want to do the same, calculating the product in each call of the

`k *(stirling (n-1) k)`

recursion, but I didn't get the hang of it. Any ideas?

P.D: The code already works quite decently, but I'm new with Haskell and I still don't know what the possibilities are. Any improvement is welcome (although I´d rater not use any library; I want to learn the basics before getting into that).

Comment: I think this question is better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looks fine for either site, @Noughtmare.

Comment: @TobySpeight Oh, I was under the impression that stackoverflow was for specific problems, whereas this question asks for general advice.

Comment: Can you clarify what "lazy evaluation taking too many memory resources" means? To say why I'm confused: the idiomatic, lazy-evaluation-based implementation of `factorial n = product [1..n]` is already about as memory efficient as it's possible to be.

Comment: @DanielWagner When I first made an implementation of the factorial function, I used regular recursion, which worked but could cause a stack overflow when working with larger inputs. With the helper auxiliary function I could get the multiplication done at each call instead of waiting until the recursion had ended for the product to begin (which is how I think the lazy evaluation works in this case).  As for the implementation you give, it is the first time I have seen it, seams quite clever.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ran out of time to edit the comment. I also wanted to point that the helper  did not only save memory but also time as it would perform the product at each call, which is what i wanted to emulate in the stirling implenetation if possible

Comment: It is possible to make implementations of `factorial` that are faster than `product [1..n]`, but not with a straightforward loop. (GHC is already smart enough to compile that into a straightforward loop under the hood on your behalf.) You would need to switch to something like tree folding or similar. I discuss this a bit more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856657/791604).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation already appears to be fairly memory efficient, at least in my tests. For example:

```
% time ./test salferdez 32 16
1194461517469807833782085
11.50user 0.00system 0:11.48elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 8704maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1267minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Changing the parameters (up *or* down) doesn't seems to change the 8MB residency much, so I expect that's just about the minimum startup cost of a Haskell program. On the other hand, it seems quite slow. Parameters even slightly larger than the ones I used here -- say, double them both -- took longer than I cared to wait. Simply implementing the formula from Wikipedia directly appears to be quite a lot faster, while retaining a good memory profile:

```
% time ./test dmwit 32 16
1194461517469807833782076
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.01elapsed 16%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4352maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+206minor)pagefaults 0swaps
% time ./test dmwit 10000 5000
<snip'd very very long output>
10.62user 0.02system 0:10.62elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 16716maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+26643minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

(I did not recompile between these runs and the previous ones, so you can be sure we both got the same level of optimization.)

On the other hand, I do get a slightly different answer than you. Perhaps you can spot a bug in one or the other of our code. In any case, [here's the formula from wikipedia](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/130dd5d9482321d31c27b68ff4a8be9e04423421)<sup>*</sup>, and here's my take on its most direct translation:

```
stirling n k = sum [(-1)^(k-i)*i^n`div`(product [1..k-i]*product[1..i]) | i <- [0..k]]
```

Don't forget to compile with `-O2` and let GHC do all the dirty work of thinking about how to make it fast and memory-efficient.

<sup>*</sup> StackOverflow does have a mechanism for including the image directly, rather than linking it, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. Not sure why!

Comment: As for the results, I check them in [this stirling number calculator](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=431). As for your sugestions, while I don´t know anything about many things you said, I´ll make sure to learn about them. As for your implementation giving sligthly different answers, I doubt about the formula. I never learned about it in the Discrete mathematics class in university, and going to the source in Wikipedia , the formula is not closed and the preceding phrase is : "the best we can do for a “closed” formula is the following", which sounds more like approximating to the result

Comment: @salferdez Hm. Where do you see that text? A search for "closed" on [the Wikipedia page I'm looking at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) comes up empty.

Comment: check reference number two of the wikipedia page and then look for Theorem 3.4.1 in the referenced web site

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a very detailed explanation right now, but you can make it quite a bit faster by:

- Using Mathematics simplify some formulas
- Using bit shifts instead of division
- Using `Int` for the input instead of `Integer`

Then you get this:

```
import Data.Bits

stirling :: Int -> Int -> Integer
stirling n 1 = 1
stirling n 2 = (1 `unsafeShiftL` (n - 1)) - 1
stirling n k
    | k > n        = 0
    | k == n       = 1
    | k == (n - 1) = fromIntegral ((n * (n - 1)) `unsafeShiftR` 1)
    | otherwise    = stirling (n - 1) (k - 1) + fromIntegral k * stirling (n - 1) k
```

The next thing I would try is dynamic programming to avoid reduntant computation.

And you use the *accumulator style* to make one of the non tail recursive calls tail recursive like they do in this blog post: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/blog/20190728-free-variable-traversals.html